# Helper.rb Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my spec folder, I have both a rails_helper.rb file and a spec_helper.rb file. If I have nothing being required for rails_helper.rb, is it safe to delete? Is there any difference or pros and cons to either? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can delete *rails_helper.rb* if you're not referencing it. The distinction between the 2 files is more one of convention. Generally, *spec_helper.rb* is used by RSpec for setting up the testing environment, while *rails_helper.rb* is a bit of a perversion on the more conventional *test_helper.rb* -- which is generally used by Test::Unit and MiniTest. So, just as a matter of avoiding confusion for other/future developers you should use the file name that fits for your test suite and not have 2 of them sitting around.

Comment: Thanks so much pdobb! I'd vote up your vote, but I'm 1 away from having enough rep to! Thanks again!

Comment: Now you should be able to :) But certainly you can accept the answer at least.

Comment: Thanks! It's my birthday so I'll take that as an e-gift! Have a great day!

Comment: Happy birthday. I thought your question was good anyway. I remember puzzling over the same thing not too long ago.